# Crop image using a fixed-size draggable picturebox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, crop

I'm working on a winforms project that involves cropping an image. My goal is to do this by using a fixed-size draggable picturebox control, allowing the user to select the area they want to preserve.

My problem is when I crop the image; it *"works"*, but the crop area offsets a little. Here's the result I get:

[image: Original image]
[image: Cropped image]

To clarify, I'm not talking about the zooming, that's per design. Notice the orange box is mostly focusing on the eye of the storm, but the cropped image is not.

This is my code for the crop operation:

```cs
private void tsbRecortar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle recorte = new Rectangle(pbxSeleccion.Location.X, pbxSeleccion.Location.Y, pbxSeleccion.Width, pbxSeleccion.Height);

    foto = recortarImagen(foto, recorte);
    pbxImagen.Image = foto;
}

private Image recortarImagen(Image imagen, Rectangle recuadro)
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imagen);
        Bitmap cropedBitmap = bitmap.Clone(recuadro, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        return (Image)(cropedBitmap);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");

        return null;
    }
}
```

***pbxSeleccion*** is the draggable orange rectangle; its parent is ***pbxImage*** (I re-parent it on form's load).

As you can see, I'm using the coordinates of *pbxSeleccion* to define the starting point of the crop area, but is not working as expected... sometimes, I even get an "Out of Memory" exception.

I think this has to do with how the image loads in the parent picturebox, something about how the margin is handled "under the hood", but nothing I tried fixes it... just changes the magnitude of the offset.

Searching the web and SO has helped me a lot, but for this particular issue, I can't seem to find an answer... please, feel free to point out improvements to my code, I haven't been coding for long and I'm new to C# and .NET

Any help is highly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your original image is displayed in a `PictureBox`. You **passed in the wrong location of the orange cropping window**. Here is the corrected code for you:

```
private void tsbRecortar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  Point p = yourPictureBox.PointToClient(pbxSelection.PointToScreen(Point.Empty));
  Rectangle recorte = new Rectangle(p.X, p.Y, pbxSeleccion.Width, pbxSeleccion.Height);

  foto = recortarImagen(foto, recorte);
  pbxImagen.Image = foto;
}
```

I use `PointToClient` and `PointToScreen` here because I think it's the best way to do. You can then change the container of your `pictureBox` safely without having to modify the code. If you use the code like the following, it's not dynamically enough when you want to place your `pictureBox` in another container:

```
Rectangle recorte = new Rectangle(pbxSeleccion.X + yourPictureBox.Left,
                                  pbxSeleccion.Y + yourPictureBox.Top, 
                                  pbxSeleccion.Width, pbxSeleccion.Height);
```

**NOTE**: you can also use `RectangleToClient` and `RectangleToScreen` like this:

```
private void tsbRecortar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   Rectangle recorte = yourPictureBox.RectangleToClient(pbxSeleccion.RectangleToScreen(pbxSeleccion.ClientRectangle));
   foto = recortarImagen(foto, recorte);
   pbxImagen.Image = foto;
}
```

Comment: Great, worked like a charm! Thanks for taking the time to reply. I noticed part the error is coming from me setting the *SizeMode* of the image loaded in **pbxImagen** to *CenterImage*.

It can be done, but I'd need to account for the left margin once the image is centered - I'll work on that and update this.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code for Cropping the Image in picturebox

```
    public static Image Fit2PictureBox(this Image image, PictureBox picBox)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        Graphics g;

        // Scale:
        double scaleY = (double)image.Width / picBox.Width;
        double scaleX = (double)image.Height / picBox.Height;
        double scale = scaleY < scaleX ? scaleX : scaleY;

        // Create new bitmap:
        bmp = new Bitmap(
            (int)((double)image.Width / scale),
            (int)((double)image.Height / scale));

        // Set resolution of the new image:
        bmp.SetResolution(
            image.HorizontalResolution,
            image.VerticalResolution);

        // Create graphics:
        g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        // Set interpolation mode:
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        // Draw the new image:
        g.DrawImage(
            image,
            new Rectangle(          // Ziel
                0, 0,
                bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
            new Rectangle(          // Quelle
                0, 0,
                image.Width, image.Height),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        // Release the resources of the graphics:
        g.Dispose();

        // Release the resources of the origin image:
        image.Dispose();

        return bmp;
    }       

    public static Image Crop(this Image image, Rectangle selection)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = image as Bitmap;

        // Check if it is a bitmap:
        if (bmp == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Kein gültiges Bild (Bitmap)");

        // Crop the image:
        Bitmap cropBmp = bmp.Clone(selection, bmp.PixelFormat);

        // Release the resources:
        image.Dispose();

        return cropBmp;
    }
```

Write The Following Code For Mouse Event on PictureBox

```
        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                _selecting = true;
                _selection = new Rectangle(new Point(e.X, e.Y), new Size());
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && _selecting)
            {
                // Create cropped image:
                try
                {
                    Image img = pictureBox1.Image.Crop(_selection);


                    // Fit image to the picturebox:
                    pictureBox1.Image = img.Fit2PictureBox(pictureBox1);
                }
                catch { }
                _selecting = false;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Update the actual size of the selection:
            if (_selecting)
            {
                _selection.Width = e.X - _selection.X;
                _selection.Height = e.Y - _selection.Y;

                // Redraw the picturebox:
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_selecting)
            {
                // Draw a rectangle displaying the current selection
                Pen pen = Pens.LightSkyBlue;
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, _selection);
            }
        }
```

Output Screen

1. Before Cropping

[image]

2. After Cropping

[image]