# How can I select part of an image in a picturebox and showing a sizable selection box?

Tags: c#, image, select, picturebox, windows-forms-designer

I need to select with a rectangle part of an image in a picturebox and I'd like to show the selection rectangle and be able to move/resize that rectangle so then i can crop the part of the picture below that rectangle. In Paint.net is done with the "Rectangle Select" and "Move Selection" tools. I need to do it in a c# Windows form application (any release, I'm already using VS 2017). Is there anything already similar in the framework or do I need to do everything from scratch by handling mouse down/up/move and somehow draw the rectangle above my image?

No, it's not a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crop image using a fixed-size draggable picturebox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929261/crop-image-using-a-fixed-size-draggable-picturebox)

Comment: You will need to do it all from scratch.

Comment: Use WPF and be done with WinForms.

Comment: @MoonKnight LOL! WPF is dead and Microsoft is keeping it alive just for those that got fooled by it..

Comment: It's dead yet they have written Visual Studio using it and the new version of SQL MS 2016 is written using it. Hmmmm...

Comment: @MoonKnight didnt know exist a product call SQL MS 2016, if you intended Microsoft SQL Server, I doubt they used WPF and .net at all for that.. maybe at most some UIs to manage it..

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2016, written using WPF (piggy-backing on Visual Studio). The fact that Visual Studio is written in WPF speaks for itself. The way VSCode is going is interesting though. Long and short is WPF is miles better for everything desktop orientated...